# Getting internal value of a type OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

I have just begun to write OCaml code lately hence this might be a naive question.But i could not figure this out myself.

I have the following type declaration in OCaml.

```
type myType =
| Int of int
```

Now i have an object of type myType.

Is there a way to access the value of int that this object holds? If yes, how?

Comment: Btw, `object` is not correct term in this context. I think you should say `value of myType`.
OCaml allows OOP and object is a term another entities. But objects are values too.

Comment: If your teaching material does not include an answer to this question in a prominent place, you need to get better material. Have a look at this StackOverflow question, [Which English tutorial would you advise to learn OCaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9358553/298143), for pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is to get an `int` value from a value of union types. In OCaml, we often use pattern matching to decompose and transform values:

```
let get_int v = 
    match v with 
    | Int i -> i
```

When you try the function in OCaml top-level, you get something like:

```
# let v = Int 3;;
val v : myType = Int 3
# get_int v;;
- : int = 3
```

If your unions types have more cases, you simply add more patterns to `get_int` functions and process them in an appropriate way.

For single-case unions like your example, you could do pattern matching directly on their values:

```
# let (Int i) = v in i;;
- : int = 3
```

Comment: Thank you! That saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

You can access the value using pattern matching:

```
match value_of_my_type with
| Int i -> do_something_with i
```