# Ocaml - using one function in another

Tags: function, ocaml

I'm learning Ocaml and having hard time understanding how to use first function as argument of another.

For example, I created a function bigger

```
# let bigger (a,b) = match (a,b) with
  (a,b) -> if a > b then true else false;;
  val bigger : 'a * 'a -> bool = <fun>

# bigger (2,3);;
- : bool = false
# bigger (3,2);;
- : bool = true
```

Now I'm struggling to use this function as an argument in function sortPair - it sorts both elements:
 - if bigger = true then (a,b)
 - if bigger = false then (b,a)

I'm sure it's a very simple solution, but I really want to understand this basic problem before moving on further.

This is what I tried:

```
# let sortPair (a,b) = match (a,b) with
  bigger (a,b) -> if true then (a,b) else (b,a);;
```

Comment: `# let bigger (a,b) = if a>b then true else false;;` works also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the basic syntax of `match` right. You should look carefully at your learning material (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358553/which-english-tutorial-would-you-advise-to-learn-ocaml) for pointers to beginners material).

Given that `bigger (a, b)` returns a boolean, you can use the `if .. then .. else` form:

```
if bigger(a,b) then ... else ...
```

Comment: I tried with if .. then .. else but always get Syntax error. I will try to figure out something and get back the answer when i have it. 

Thank you for that learning material.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i did exactly as @gasche said, it's a very simple solution after all, I complicated the problem for no reason:

```
# let sortPair (a,b) = if bigger (a,b) then (a,b) else (b,a);;
val sortPair : 'a * 'a -> 'a * 'a = <fun>

# sortPair (2,3);;
- : int * int = (3, 2)
```

I did get a little different syntax that i was hoping for though.

```
('a*'a -> ('a*'a -> bool) -> 'a*'a)
```

Comment: What type were you expecting from the function?

Comment: `('a*'a -> ('a*'a -> bool) -> 'a*'a)`

Comment: If you want that type, you would want to pass a function along with the pair to `sortPair`. Like, `let sortPair (a,b) f = if f (a,b) then (a,b) else (b,a)`, and call it like `sortPair (2,3) bigger`.